# execute command on icmp request

Tags: networking, ping, icmp, exec

I'd like to know how/if it is possible to get my linux (ubuntu) box to exec a command (script) on incoming icmp/ping (or other network events) requests?

Like e.g. playing a "ping" sound when being pinged, or playing an alert sound on specific source IP match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that to do this with a dedicated program (that intercepts IP packets) would be a fairly heavyweight bit of programming. If this is just a casual thing then judicious use of logging with iptables or tcpdump along with tail to watch the log and a simple shell script or scripts would do the job.